# how to get the exact total by month?

Tags: php, mysql

I have mySQL table for my data project.each table row is includes id,date,time and qty.

```
id   | date | time |  qty
-------------------------
```

I would like to query it so I can generate a HTML table with a report looking like this:

[image]

I need to sum all of qty and to a total, for a month. How would I do that use php?

this is my code that i have tried...

```html
<table width="522" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900">
    <tr bgcolor="#FF9900">
    <td bgcolor="#333333" colspan="7" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><strong>List of Shopping</strong></td>
    </tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FF9900">
<td  align="center"><font face="Lato"  color="#D30CAB"><strong>MONTH</a></strong></font></td>
<td align="center"><font face="Lato"  color="#D30CAB"><strong>QUANTITY</strong></font></td>
<td align="center"><font face="Lato"  color="#D30CAB"><strong>DELETE</strong></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
include('connection.php');
$user_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `buy` WHERE 1");
while($user_rows=mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900"><?php echo $user_rows['date'] ; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900"><?php echo $user_rows['qty'] ; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900"><a href="delete2.php<?php echo '?id='.$user_rows['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
  </main>
 <?php
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT sum(qty) FROM buy") or die(mysql_error());
 while ($user_rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?> 
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Some code please and dummy data

Comment: Use MySQL `Group By` and `SUM` functions

Comment: i have edit in my question @RyanVincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would use something similiar to the following query:

```
SELECT
MONTH(date) as month,
SUM(qty) as total
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date) = 5
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then, using a foreach or a while (depending on the way you execute your query) loop through the array with results and build your table.

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $result['month']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $result['total']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above is some pseuodo code that will help you get on the right track. Good luck!

### Edit

To help you out a bit, here is an example using your code.

```
include('connection.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT
    MONTH(date) as month,
    SUM(qty) as total
    FROM buy
    WHERE MONTH(date) = 5
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
    ORDER BY date DESC
") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());

$resource = array();
while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $results[] = $record;
}
```

Your table:

```
<table width="522" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900">
    <tr bgcolor="#FF9900">
        <td bgcolor="#333333" colspan="7" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"><strong>List of Shopping</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FF9900">
        <td  align="center"><font face="Lato"  color="#D30CAB"><strong>MONTH</a></strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Lato"  color="#D30CAB"><strong>QUANTITY</strong></font></td>
        <td align="center"><font face="Lato"  color="#D30CAB"><strong>DELETE</strong></font></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2016-'.$result['month']); ?>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900"><?= $date->format('M'); ?></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900"><?= $result['total']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FF9900">Deleting will not work since it is a grouped result. You ccannot delete by id.</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Note for the readers: I have used `mysql_*` because OP uses it in his code. I cannot simply ask for OP to upgrade his server before answering.

Comment: Exactly the question asked.

Comment: A good example of using PHP for templating by using `alternate control syntax` and the `short echo` tag :)

Comment: a simple answer..i will try it..tq

Comment: @RyanVincent the code is not working to me and they appear like this:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @misshwa Take another look at my answer. It will give you a better understanding of how to solve your issue.

Comment: @Peter i don't know why, it is not working..i've try your code but its still have problem.

Comment: I see your problem. Change `$user_query` to `$query`

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
    SELECT
            MONTH(`date`) AS `MONTH`, SUM(qty) AS `TOTAL`
    FROM 
            < tableName >
    GROUP BY 
            MONTH(`date`)
```

Answer (score -1):

try some thing like this:

```
select SUM(qty) as total, id, MONTH(date) 
from your_table
group by MONTH(date)
```